# Why are you required to pay or have a university relation to access most research journals?

Tags: publications, online-resource

High school student here...

I came here to ask this question since it seems geared more towards academia and I normally spend my time on Math.SE. Anyway...

I have a huge passion for math, I read about it and work on problems every day. At this point in time I'm even considering going into academia for math research (although it seems incredibly difficult to land professorship based on the things I've read here.) In my ongoing research, I've noticed that there are very few places to freely read mathematical papers. I tend to turn to the arXiv so this isn't so much a problem - except for the times I come across a paper with a particularly interesting abstract, only to find its host site asking for one of two things:

1. An association with an institution or research group
2. Monthly payment

So my question is do any of the academics here have any insight as to why that is? Are the authors of the papers compensated with part of the payment received by the journal?

(Sorry if this question comes across as very naive but, admittedly, I am.)

Comment: Did you try searching this site for an answer? I'm sure this has been asked before

Comment: Why does your local paper charge you to get a copy?

Comment: @Jon Custer Are you asking seriously or in an attempt to provide reasoning for my question?

Comment: Thank you for providing the link. I'm currently reading over the thread now.

Comment: I just marked as duplicate.

Comment: There's a bit of a difference between asking about the requirements for accessing journals (simple answer: they prefer to sell access rather than support their business via ads or something, and only research libraries want to pay for that access), versus asking why the researchers themselves continue to freely give their content to such journals.